# Pentaho CDE Chart

Tags: charts, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I am trying to create a line chart in pentaho (CDE). But what I see that happens is: first query column goes into dimension, and all the rest go into expressions. But what I need to do is this:

columns:
Year, Type, Value

I need Year to be the X axe and then paint a line for each Type, with its Value beeing the Y axe.

I don't see how I can do this. Is it with chart properties, or changing my sql query, or even with javascript?

Thanks

Comment: try protovis chart component

Comment: I already am using that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your data to have crosstabMode = false.

And I believe you'll need to switch the category and series roles: add "series" to the categoryRole option and "category" to the seriesRole option (both under advanced properties).

Comment: Thanks, this totally worked. 
Where can I find documentation about this? I just typed what you said in categoryRole and seriesRole and it worked, but I don't see how I could have figured it out.

Comment: The documentation is almost non-existant. Whatever exists is here: http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cde.html and here: http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ccc.html. It's pretty much a matter of reading the examples, the source code and practice.